# Java lists strange size malfunction

Tags: java, arraylist

I initialize a list, like this:

```
public List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>(8);
```

After that, I would like to get its size, but following code gives zero.

```
System.out.println("SIZE: " + edges.size());
```

There isn't any value change or method call beetwen two lines.
What can causes this?

Comment: The constructor you use instantiate an array with the given capacity. `size()` gives the number of elements in the list, not the underlying array length. Those things are unrelated.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to your [**constructor**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) is the *capacity*.

The capacity is the number of elements that the underlying array can hold before it needs resizing.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a List is the amount of elements in it, not the size you initialized it with.

Comment: Yes, but when I try to add an element I get an exception.

Comment: What kind of exception? without a stacktrace I can't help you.

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

Comment: what about a stacktrace?

Comment: Use the "add" method without an index, since you have no positions to insert into yet (with size 0). That is: "add(obj)" instead of "add(0, obj)".

Comment: There are values in it, I have tested. This exception comes, when I try to replace them.